# extjs Panel fit layout

Tags: extjs

I have a panel and i am rendering it into a container. I want the `panel` to fit into the `container` height and don't want to specify the height of the `panel`.

But don't seem to work is there a way I could do it.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
<div id=Div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
var newPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'newPanel',
    renderTo: 'Div',
    layout: 'fit',
    border: false,
    items: [anotherPanel]
})
```

any ideas please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this plugin: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?28318-Fit-to-parent&highlight=fitToParent

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'fit' layout on the container, and set autoheight and autowidth to false on the child panel. The fit layout should take care of making the components inside it automagically 'fit'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code:

```
autoHeight: true
```