# How do I set Extjs panel's layouts to fit to whole page?

Tags: javascript, extjs, layout, panel

I'm developing a web application with [Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/) in client side. In first level of my page, I have a panel(panel_a). **I want to this panel fit to the whole page**.

In this panel I have another panel(panel_b). **I want to fit this panel in panel_a too**.

How do I set the panel's layouts?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`viewport`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.plugin.Viewport) plugin on `panel_a` to fit it to the whole page, and [`fit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit) layout to fit `panel_b` into it:

```js
{
    itemId: 'panel_a',
    xtype: 'panel',
    plugins: 'viewport',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        itemId: 'panel_b',
        xtype: 'panel'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share source code. :-) But I think that you should use container: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/layouts.html 
This is very good sample page: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

1:
[extjs Panel fit layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603924/extjs-panel-fit-layout)
2:
[Difference between anchor layout and fit layout in Sencha ExtJs 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471715/difference-between-anchor-layout-and-fit-layout-in-sencha-extjs-5)